# How to fix corrupted text in *Backtrace* buffer (emacs)

Tags: emacs, elisp

When debug-on-error is enabled, I have trouble with corrupted text in *Backtrace* buffer. 
like this.

**example**
[image]

it says maybe in Japanese. However, I can't understand the message.
Does anyone know workaround? it will be ok for me to display the message in English.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**conditions**

OS: Ubuntu 14.10

emacs version: 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.12.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is bytecode. No, it should not be shown in backtraces. Or at least there should be a user option not to show it in backtraces.

This is Emacs [bug #6991](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6991), which was reported 4 years ago.

Sadly, it has not been fixed, and was simply moved to "*Wishlist*" (effectively aka `/dev/null`).

([Bug #15789](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15789) also complained about byte-code in backtraces.)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I understand why.

Comment: Bug #6991 appears to have been [fixed in June 2017](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6991#210). Better late than never :)

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers say, this is bytecode. You see this because emacs hasn't evaluated the source code. This utility of this might be debatable; sometimes the byte code can give hints about what is going on, though.

To remedy this problem, you should got to the helm source code (just click on one of the functions, like `helm-update` and then `M-x eval-buffer`). After that, you *should* see a more meaningful backtrace. (I couldn't test this though: I installed helm via `package-install` and after `debug-on-entry helm-apropos` and `helm-apropos`, I didn't see any byte code. How did you install helm?)

Comment: Thank you for your rapid reply. I installed helm with package-install from MELPA.(helm-20141106.257). In order to load .el file insted of .elc file of helm, I deleted .elc file in helm directory. then, any error does't occur. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

That's not text in any human language, but Emacs byte code, compiled from Emacs Lisp.  (I'm not sure why this is displayed in the backtrace buffer — it might as well be hidden by default, since it's unlikely to help in resolving any problems.)

What you can read from the above is that the function `helm-mp-highlight-region` is calling `re-search-forward` with a `nil` argument, but `re-search-forward` expects a string instead.  This might be a bug in Helm.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid reply. I understand why the text seems to be corrupted.